# How do i parse xml to display contents in android emulator?

Tags: php, android, xml, http

I have an external mysql database on my own host and i have also created the php file on the server side which will extract the records from the database and put them in to xml format. (shown below)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die("Could not      connect to host.");
mysql_select_db("footieDB") or die("Could not find database.");
$resultID=mysql_query("select * from league"); //$resultID was $sql


$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "<leagues>\n"; 

for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++){ 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID); 
    $xml_output .= "\t<league>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<leagueID>" . $row['leagueID'] . "</leagueID>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<leagueName>" . $row['leagueName'] . "</leagueName>\n"; 
    $xml_output .= "\t</league>\n"; 
} 

$xml_output .= "</leagues>"; 

echo $xml_output;

mysql_close();
?>
```

I am wondering how do I parse this xml in order to display the info in the android emulator.
Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.google.com.ng/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=parse+xml+android

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, you should probably put the data in JSON format instead of XML.  XML parsing is no fun, and JSONs are quick and easy.  If you're determined though:

```
String example1;
String example2;
// establish a connection with the server
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www........./your_stuff.xml");

            // execute the post and get the response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            byte[] responsebody = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
            String result = new String(responsebody, 0, responsebody.length, "UTF-8");

            // Go through the XML with an XML pull parser, identifying items
            // by their tag names
            final XmlPullParser xpp = Xml.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput(new StringReader(result));
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("example1")) {
                        eventType = xpp.next();
                        example1 = xpp.getText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("example2")) {
                        eventType = xpp.next();
                        example2 = xpp.getText();
                    }
                } 
            eventType = xpp.next();
            }
           ....... etc
```